# Note Array Differences - Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have two arrays. One is a set of skills, the other is a set of skills that a user can do. To illustrate :

```
['swimming', 'rowing', 'cycling'] is the set of all skills
```

Now, a user can have its set of skills like :

```
['rowing', 'cycling']
```

How can i create a nice hash that will present whether a user has a current skill ? Like for this particular user, it would be :

```
{'swimming' => no, 'rowing' => yes, 'cycling', => yes}
```

*P.S. I actually want to do this with active record objects in rails, but i suppose it's the same idea.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following will give `true` and `false` instead of `yes` and `no`.

```
all_skills = %w[swimming rowing cycling]
user_skills = %w[rowing cycling]

Hash[all_skills.map{|k| [k, user_skills.include?(k)]}]
```

or, if you don't mind getting `nil` instead for the `no` cases, the following is faster.

```
Hash[user_skills.map{|k| [k, true]}]}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's one terse way to do that:

```
ALL_SPORTS = ['swimming', 'rowing', 'cycling']

user_array = ['rowing', 'cycling']
user_hash = ALL_SPORTS.inject(Hash.new) { |h, sport| {sport => user_array.include?(sport)}.merge(h) }
```

Answer (score 2):

I am presuming when you say 'yes' and 'no' you really want boolean values.  The following doesn't use any intermediate values and only relies on the user's defined sports:

```
> h = Hash.new(false).merge(Hash[%w[rowing swimming].map {|v| [v.to_sym, true]}])
 => {:rowing=>true, :swimming=>true}
```

Now if you invoke any other sport as a key that the user doesn't have you get the desired result:

```
> h[:golf]
 => false
```

This also assumes you want symbols for keys too.